# Find the roots of the summed polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, contest-math

> Find the roots of: $$x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 0$$

I got that:

$$\frac{1 - x^8}{1-x} - x^6 - x = 0$$

But that doesnt make it any easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A start: The polynomial factors as $(x^3+1)(x^4+x^2+1)$.

Answer (score 7):

$$x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 0$$
$$(x^7 + x^4) + (x^5 + x^3) + x^2 + 1 = 0$$
$$x^4(x^3 + 1) + x^3(x^2 + 1) + x^2 + 1 = 0$$

$$x^4(x^3 + 1) + (x^2 + 1)(x^3 + 1) = 0$$

$$(x^3 + 1)(x^4+x^2 + 1) = 0$$
from there we can continue with factoring
$$x^3+1=x^3+1^3=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
and
$$x^4+x^2 + 1 =(x^2)^2+2x^2+1-x^2=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=$$
$$=(x^2+1-x)(x^2+1+x)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1}{x+1}=x^6-x^5+2x^4-x^3+2x^2-x+1$

$=x^6-x^5+x^4+(x^4-x^3+x^2)+(x^2-x+1)$

$=x^4(x^2-x+1)+x^2(x^2-x+1)+(x^2-x+1)$

$=(x^2-x+1)[x^4+x^2+1]$

Now $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-(x)^2=\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

Clever factoring: $x^7+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1 =(x+1)(x^2 - x + 1)(x^4+x^2+1)$

Comment: and $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$. Note the double factor.